# Escape Becomes Ctrl-Z - but why?

Tags: vb6

I am currently maintaining a VB6 app, but have very little knowledge of VB6.
I have come across a bit of code which has me perplexed.

```
Private Sub Form_KeyPress(KeyAscii As Integer)
  KeyAscii = Asc(UCase(Chr(KeyAscii)))
  If KeyAscii = 27 And TypeOf Me.ActiveControl Is TextBox Then
      KeyAscii = 0
      SendKeys "^Z"
  End If
End Sub
```

Here's what I know: the code is invoking a keypress of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> when the escape button is pressed.
Here's what I don't know: why? I debugged through after clicking escape, and apart from the contents of the if statement being run through, it doesn't do much that I can percieve (apart from the fleeting display of a cursor).

Does anyone know the importance of this? i.e. sending a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keypress combination.

Comment: Extremely clumsy way to do undo on current textbox. Moreover, it will do a redo on second <kbd>Esc</kbd> being pressed. Best would be to use API with `EM_CANUNDO` and then `EM_UNDO` if there is anything in undo queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> keystroke will be passed on to the control with keyboard focus. Some controls have limited support for undoing recent edits: particularly the textbox.

So this is probably a quick-and-dirty way to associate a non-standard key (<kbd>Esc</kbd>) with the action of undoing the latest edit. You won't find any more source code for the keypress in the VB6 code, because the keypress is actually being handled by the Windows controls.

Comment: Thanks Mark. Undo makes sense. I'll try it tomorrow to verify.

Answer (score 4):

A <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is the end-of-file character for DOS-based systems unlike the (usually, though configurable) <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> in UNIX-like systems.

However, I think it more likely in this case to be an undo command, given that it's happening within a textbox.

That would be my first guess, that you need to send that keystroke to revert any changes you've made.

One way to test that theory would be to make a change in the textbox, then do the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to see if it reverts.

Of course, a given application is free to interpret the keystroke in any way it sees fit. You should probably look into the code to see what <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is meant to do.

Comment: +1 Although onefootswill probably cannot look into *all* the code to see what CTRL-Z does, because the keystroke is probably passed on into native Windows controls, e.g. textbox (which has some limited built-in support for undoing recent edits). So that would involve stepping into Microsoft's VB6 runtime libraries and then stepping on down into the Windows source code :)

Answer (score 1):

Your question is out of context of the application so there's no way to answer for sure, however, from a historical perspective, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> is an `ASCII` end of file marker (`EOF`, `ASCII 26`) and in the Digital Equipment Corp, and DOS world used to be used where escape (`ESC`, `ASCII 27`), is now commonly used.  That is, to escape from a situation, users used to type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> rather than striking the escape key.

I suspect it's a leftover piece of compatibility code.

Comment: Thanks simple. Historical context is helpful. It's a forms app, so console-related stuff won't really apply. Cheers